# Making a line of dashes?

Tags: python

This is the code im a using to try to achieve the output '_ _ _ _' based on the number of letters in word

```
def maskLetters(mask,word):
    index=0
    while index<len(word):
        print mask+mask
        index=index+1
```

Answer (score 7):

```
def maskLetters(mask, word):
    print mask * len(word)
```

(I've made some assumptions about what you meant by your `mask` parameter.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want spaces in between

```
def maskLetters(mask, word):
    return ' '.join(mask * len(word))
```

Also

```
def maskLetters(mask, word):
    return ' '.join(word.translate(mask*256))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can multiply a `str` by an `int` and it returns that `str` repeated `int` times:

```
def maskLetters(mask,word):
    print len(word) * mask # length of the word * mask to repeat

> maskLetters('_', 'cow')
___
> maskLetters('f','stackoverflow')
fffffffffffff
```

Comment: its to be in the form '_ _ _ _' if I entered the word "Ball"

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> word = 'John'
>>> print repr('_ ' * len(word))
'_ _ _ _'
```

Comment: Edited to add a repr.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
>>> word='Ball'
>>> ul='-'
>>> print("'{}'\n'{:{fill}^{w}}'".format(word,ul,fill=ul,w=len(word)))
'Ball'
'----'
```